# Sum of lines with the same value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with football (soccer) stats with a gameID (which game it is), a leagueID (which of the Big Five leagues the game "belongs" to), goals scored and fouls commited. The problem is that the data frame contains each team, so the GameID is doubled. In order to get an outside view of the game result, I like to sum up the results to have a final result of one GameID.

I have this data frame:

| GameID | leagueID | goals | fouls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 1 | 1 | 12 |
| 81 | 1 | 0 | 12 |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ------ |
| 83 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 83 | 1 | 2 | 13 |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ------ |
| 88 | 1 | 0 | 12 |
| 88 | 1 | 2 | 9 |

I would like to have this result:

| GameID | leagueID | goals | fouls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 1 | 1 | 24 |
| 83 | 1 | 4 | 20 |
| 88 | 1 | 2 | 21 |

I tried to create new columns with "rowSums". My problem is that I need the sum for each GameID and no the sum of the whole rows.

Comment: Are you mixing up columns and rows?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 1):

You could use `group_by`and `summarize`to get a summarised table.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%  #the name of your dataframe
  group_by(GameID) %>%  
  summarise(leagueID  = mean(leagueID),
            goals = sum(goals),
            fouls = sum(fouls))
```

Comment: As evident from M aurélio's answer, you might want to add the leagueID to the grouping variable

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with **dplyr** grouping by GameID and LeagueID

```
library(dplyr)

games <-
tribble(
     ~GameID,  ~leagueID,    ~goals,   ~fouls,
        81,        1,       1,     12,
        81,        1,       0,     12,
        83,        1,       2,      7,
        83,        1,       2,     13,
        88,        1,       0,     12,
        88,        1,       2,      9
  )

games |> 
  group_by(GameID,leagueID) |> 
  summarise(goals_sum = sum(goals), fouls_sum = sum(fouls))
```